# Scrapy only going through first 5 links with next_page_url

Tags: python, scrapy

My code seemingly only goes through the first 5 links that are requested and then stops when the 6th is requested. I have tried to use start_urls and next_page_url. Both only extract from the first 5 pages given.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import time
class finvizSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    global tickers
    global urlcheck
    urlcheck = 1
    tickers = []
    name = "finviz"

    start_urls =  ["https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=change"]

    def parse(self, response):


        tickers.append(response.xpath('//a[@class="screener-link-primary"]/text()').extract())
        print(tickers)
        next_page_url = "https://finviz.com/"
        html = response.xpath(
            '//a[@class="screener_arrow"]/@href').extract()[0]
        print(html)
        next_page_url += html
        print(next_page_url)
        if next_page_url is not None:

            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
    def returnTickers(self):
        newTickerList= []
        for lists in tickers:
            if lists:
                for t in lists:
                    newTickerList.append(t)
        return newTickerList
```

Here is the error statement:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have updated the code, but still seem to get errors.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
class finvizSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    global tickers
    global urlcheck
    urlcheck = 1
    tickers = []
    name = "finviz"

    start_urls = [
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-change"]

    def parse(self, url):
        raw_html = scrapy.Request(url)
        good_html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
        first_part = "https://finviz.com/"
        tickers.append([x.text for x in good_html.findAll('a', {'class': 'screener-link-primary'})])
        second_part = good_html.find('a', {'class': 'screener_arrow'})['href']

        # Check if there is next page
        if second_part:
            next_url = first_part + second_part
            self.parse(next_url)
    def returnTickers(self):
        newTickerList= []
        for lists in tickers:
            if lists:
                for t in lists:
                    newTickerList.append(t)
        return newTickerList


stock_list = finvizSpider()
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(finvizSpider)
process.start()
list2 = stock_list.returnTickers()
```

I get the following error when this is run.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if next_page_url is not None:` will never be None, You need to check if html is None.

The line `next_page_url += html` will give you an error when html is None, so first you need to check if it's None.

If html is None, then you can't do html[0], replace extract with extract_first (I used get).

**Here is the fixed code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import time


class FinvizSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "finviz"

    urlcheck = 1
    tickers = []

    start_urls = ["https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=change"]


    def parse(self, response):
        self.tickers.append(response.xpath('//a[@class="screener-link-primary"]/text()').extract())
        print(self.tickers)
        next_page_url = "https://finviz.com/"
        html = response.xpath('//a[@class="screener_arrow"]/@href').get()
        print(html)
        if html is not None:
            next_page_url += html
            print(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def returnTickers(self):
        newTickerList= []
        for lists in self.tickers:
            if lists:
                for t in lists:
                    newTickerList.append(t)
        return newTickerList
```

Comment: I am still only getting 5 links to work and the same error shows up when going for 6.

Comment: I works fine for me. Did you copy it exactly like I wrote?, also what error do you get? the last few lines are missing from the photo.

Comment: So I ran it again and there were no errors. There is still a problem though. It is only getting 6 page responses. If you go to the website you will see that there is 11.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer I was able to put a sleep of .02 seconds in between yields which is perfectly acceptable. If you have another other input on this though I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like scrapy can only callback 5 times, so instead of callingback i would recommend to iterate over a list with all the links, you can do it with BeautifulSoup and it would be very simple.

## Install

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

## BS4 import:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

## Rest of code:

```
def parse(self, url):
    raw_html    = scrapy.Request(url)
    good_html   = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    first_part  = "https://finviz.com/"
    tickers.append([x.text for x in good_html.findAll('a', {'class':'screener-link-primary'})])
    second_part = good_html.find('a', {'class':'screener_arrow'})['href']

    # Check if there is next page
    if second_part:
        next_url    = first_part + second_part
        self.parse(next_url)
```

Comment: Should this be used outside the scrapy spider class?

Comment: I rewrote your parse function (inside your finvizSpider). If you mean the import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, yes it should be outside the spider class. And yes you could use this outside finvizSpider class

Comment: Please see the original post for edits. It seems I am getting errors with the code. Thanks